# Why there are so many great/famous questions which does not even satisfy the SO 'ask a question'criteria

Tags: discussion

Referring to question like [Differences between HashMap and Hashtable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471/differences-between-hashmap-and-hashtable)  I wonder how could it be accepted as it satisfy none of criteria mentioned in SO. I should be able to flag it off-topic as it falls under
 *Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself*. And also
  *Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist*

I don't doubt about the quality and importance of the questions but to me the rule supposed to be same for all. And the very first line in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) clearly says

> **First, make sure that your question is on-topic for this site**.You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

**How to Ask**

> Is your question about programming?
>
> We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.
>
> **Provide details. Share your research.**

I don't understand how these are justified in these cases? 
Some more similar entried I could find (And this list could go on)
[What is a serialVersionUID and why should I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/what-is-a-serialversionuid-and-why-should-i-use-it)
[How can a string be initialized using " "?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489250/how-can-a-string-be-initialized-using/17489410#17489410)

Comment: Can you tell me when it was asked?

Comment: Fun Fact: Old and immensely useful questions don't need to satisfy all the criteria to stay on the site.

Comment: @Oded the latest one I could find was 4 months back

Comment: @Mysticial no offence but the term 'immensely useful questions' sounds a bit relative to me

Comment: I'm not gonna argue with you on that. But if you believe these questions don't belong on the site, go ahead and vote to close them. My guess is that they will stick around. From a strictly business standpoint, I figure SE gets a lot of Ad revenue from these sorts of questions due to the sheer amount search engine traffic they get.

Comment: I just want to mention only one thing. SO trusts some one by his/her reputation (if I am not wrong) .. m i supposed to trust someone who got so much reputation by asking such a question which is not even valid and I can show plenty of people getting [closed] or [on-hold] question by the same reason ..

Comment: we should not then demotivate new user by closing down their first attempt in SO . .after all we are all here to share and help

Answer (score 3):

> Questions **concerning problems with code you've written** must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself

The question is not concerning a problem with code the author wrote, so that doesn't apply.

> Questions **asking for code** must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist

The question isn't asking for code.

As for:

> Provide details. Share your research.

Yes, this question is lacking in research.  It would have been better if the author spent more time researching the differences, and demonstrated what research they had done and what they had failed to find.

When you come across questions that failed to provide enough research their is a particular tool available to you.  That tool's tooltip is:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

That tool is a downvote.  That is the appropriate response to a question you feel is not sufficiently well researched.

In this particular case, one could also make an argument for the question being "too broad", especially with respect to the second question, as it could mean a lot of things and trying to explain them all would be just too much.  As for the first question, it doesn't appear to be overly broad given the answers to the question.

---

Regardless, when you come across a question that you feel should be closed, just vote/flag it for closure.  There's no real need to start a meta question about it unless you're 1) unsure of whether or not it should be closed 2) there is a clear controversy over the question and it is constantly being reopened/closed or there is an involved discussion over it's closure in the comments.

As for why there are questions that exist that should be closed (or even are closed) but have a lot of upvotes, there are a number of reasons.  Some of those questions were once on topic, but are no longer, there are questions that people like asking/answering even though they aren't on topic, etc.  As a rule, you can ignore a questions popularity when determining if it should be opened/closed.  (However it's popularity is *highly* relevant when determining if it should be deleted.)

Comment: Can I just ask `what is the difference between Spring & Struts ?` - The question is not concerning a problem with code the author wrote, so that doesn't apply.  - The question isn't asking for code.

Comment: @user2720864 Such a question is very likely to be too broad, so closing it for that reason would be appropriate.  It would also be appropriate to downvote it for a lack of research.  It may also be a duplicate.  It doesn't meet the given closure requirements you mentioned though, for the reasons I provided here.

Comment: m a new one in this site and a great fan of SO. But m just trying to understand why handful of people are getting benefited whiles others not for the same reason.. You can spend a whole day discussion the difference between Hash table and Hash map isn't it ?

Comment: @user2720864 Not really.  They're two different implementations of the same thing.  They're *mostly* the same, with just a handful of differences, at least based on the answers I see there.  If you feel that the important differences are such that they couldn't be explained in the scope of an SO answer then you are free to case a vote for it being "too broad".

Comment: its not about being too broad, it is about type of question allowed to ask and follow policy for the site.don't know why u r even referring the answer as to me this questions are supposed to be closed or deleted in the first place and if not then every other should be given the same and equal rights to ask or start such discussion. After all what's the point of mentioning all these what to ask, how to ask policies where there are so many example of such highly voted similar posts? Sorry to say but I really do not see any reason to accept that these question were within the scope of SO

Comment: @user2720864 You're just asserting that they don't belong without actually discussing *why* they should or should not belong.  Your reasoning for why they don't belong is not correct, as I have described in my answer.  These questions may not belong for another reason that you *didn't* discuss at all, namely being "too broad" to which they are at least walking the line, and some of your other examples cross.  The answers are relevant mostly just for "too broad" considerations.  If they are huge, it's an indication there is a lot to talk about.  If they are short, it indicates the opposite.

Comment: 'You're just asserting that they don't belong without actually discussing why they should or should not belong' - I didn't just asset but was just trying to figure out One good reason to understand how could such a question can fall under on-topic category.

Comment: 'Your reasoning for why they don't belong is not correct, as I have described in my answer' - I've seen the answer but unfortunately cant relate it with the FAQ page where it says -- "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face" , what I really don't understand what does "based on actual problem you face" line signify ?

Comment: could you please tell me why http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11250028/twitter-storm-compared-to-hadoop one got closed a year back ?

Comment: @user2720864 The last question you linked is effectively "too broad".  As for the other question being a problem someone faces, it's entirely reasonable to be faced with the problem of deciding which class should be used, and therefore would need to know the differences.  That's quite practical.  It is also answerable given that it, well, has answers, and they appear to have answered the question.

Comment: I think you both might be missing the point. There's a very fuzzy line on what's allowed and what isn't. And it gets fuzzier with age since the rules have changed over the years. The problem is that one side of the line, the question gets closed and/or deleted. On the other side, it gets tons of votes because it's useful and attracts search engine traffic.

And if this is an issue of fairness: Realize that there are lottery winners. Some people asked the right question at the right time. It happens in real life. It happens in SO.

Answer (score 0):

There's a tension here between being a repository of answers to questions and expecting people to do research. The first 1/2 of that question about hash tables is a factual question that many new Java programmers need to answer. It's also one with many perfectly good answers findable on Google. Now, of course, the stackoverflow post is one of them. Further, this question dates from a time when many more questions were considered on-topic.

The question is at least in complete English sentences, does not ask 'send me the codez', and does not come decorated with irrelevancies.

The admissibility of a question depends on the community's judgement of laziness. If five people run Google queries and see good answers, it gets closed. If they don't see clear, on point, answers, it stays open. If someone asked a question at the same level today, well, I'd guess it would get closed, or at least end up in the giant close vote review pigpile.